# apprequests show count, but no app info in apps tab

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, apprequests

I'm developing a FB app, and using the apprequests object via Javascript SDK to call the invite dialog to choose friends to invite to the app. The requests are going out fine, and I see the "App Requests" count in my test user's sidebar increment. However, when I go into "App Requests" there is no app to accept.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? I've searched everywhere and followed the documentation as far as I can tell.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Adam